# how can i disable sleep mode when i turn off pc monitor (close notebook)

Tags: laptop, suspend

I like sleep with music (spotify), but when i turn off both monitor elementary go sleep mode and stop music. How can i disable sleep mode?

Thx.

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to 'System Settings'
2. Select 'Power'
3. Unlock administrator rights
4. Look down and you'll see "When lid is closed:"
5. Choose from menu to the right "Do nothing"